# Why do gases have little to no forces of attraction/repulsion?

Tags: forces, gas

I was wondering why gases have no forces of attraction or repulsion among their particles. As far as I know, the kinetic energy of these particles is great enough to overcome any such force; but aren't forces constantly acting on everything? Or is it because of the fact that gas particles are (technically) not "bound" to each other like in liquids or solids? Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, to become a gas, the particles have overcome (most) of the binding forces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attractive forces between molecules are expressions of electrostatic attraction between charge distributions.

Far from the molecule, a neutral molecule's electric field is close to zero, because as the solid angle that the molecule takes up becomes small, the molecule looks like a neutral point, not a charge distribution with spatial extent.

Very, very close to the molecule, when the electron cloud is much closer than the nucleus, the molecule's electric field is almost entirely that of the electron cloud. Like charges repel, so it is strongly repulsive of any other electron clouds. This distance is about 1 angstrom and is what gives atoms physical size and keeps them from passing through one another.

In the just-right distance between Far (0 electric field) and Adjacent (strong negative electric field), where the molecule takes up a large solid angle, its charge distribution becomes significant, with regions of net-positive and net-negative electric field. Slow-moving molecules that stay in the just-right distance for long enough can line up such that they experience an attractive force. This distance is in the single-digit angstroms. The strength, shape, and mechanics of the attractive forces vary depending on the molecules in question.

So, a gas is a substance in which molecules are moving too fast to stay in the distance regime where molecules experience an attractive force.

Answer (score 4):

You are kind of right in most of your statements but seem to miss couple crucial bits required for understanding that.

1. Forces DO constantly act on everything, but their magnitude changes drastically with distance. Consider [nuclear force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force) - it acts incredibly strong at very short distances and essentially "stops working" any further.
2. In regular gas (not plasma) atoms are electrically neutral. That means that instead of somewhat significant repulsion/attraction there is effectively only a tiny fraction of it. For some intuition on it, consider a single electron in a gas and forces acting upon it outside its respective molecule. Typical distance the molecule travels between collisions in a gas at room temperature is about 150-200 times larger than the size of that molecule. The electron under consideration is simultaneously attracted by some other nuclei and repelled by their respective electrons, thus instead of $k\dfrac{e*(Qe)}{(200d)^2}$ you are looking at $k\dfrac{e*(Qe)}{(200d)^2} - k\dfrac{e*(Qe)}{(201d)^2}\simeq k\dfrac{2e*(Qe)}{200^3*d^2},$ where d is the size of the molecule and Qe - the charge of the nucleus. This is further two orders of magnitude smaller. As molecules come closer together, this force sharply increases, they repel and keep flying around.
3. Indeed, kinetic energy is key. Think of billiards - as you hit them really hard, they would just keep bouncing around the board. As they slow down, they would come to rest and be able to "merge" together - it is much the same with gas vs liquid. And much like billiards, the forces gas molecules exert upon each other until coming in contact are essentially insignificant.